# How many bounces before removing a dead address to avoid recycled spam trap?

Tags: email-server, spam, mailing-list, email

We are developing our own mailing tool and scan log and mail error to remove dead mails from our database.

When an error 5xx is returned by mails servers, we remove the mail for a determined time (eg 80 days).

We do this because we want to try again later, if the user recreate his mail account, or if the domain shows up again atfer have been offline (because his ownwer forgot to renew it), this user will expect to still receive mails.

But I’ve discovered today the concept of dead or dormant address, and I want to avoid recycled spam traps.

Is it better to remove the bounced mails definitely from our database? What if the user’s mailbox comes back later?

Comment: "What if the user’s mailbox comes back later?" If your content's worth receiving, they'll resubscribe.

Comment: You're right. But what if it's a transactional email ?

Comment: If it's transactional, it's not a subscription.

Comment: People subscribe to our client's services, and their address may be deleted / deactivated.

Comment: Look, they either subscribe, or it's transactional. Transactional is by definition not a subscription - it is triggered by a **transaction**, like purchasing an item.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should never subscribe someone to your list without their permission, which is exactly what you are doing. If that email address does get reactivated, you have no way to know if it is the same person or not. So your email would then be unsolicited, and safely considered spam.

If you get a 5xx bounce, you should *permanently* unsubscribe the address.

Comment: +1 for being able to parse that.

Comment: I haven't seen that from this point of view, and you're right, we shouldn't try again later. But I don't know how you could presume we are subscribing people ourselves... But thanks for this clear answer.